# Calling VB6 COM Function from DotNet in multiple threads

Tags: .net, multithreading, vb6

I want to create an .net application which calls a VB6 COM function. The COM component is declared as Multiuse.

```
Private _App As ComObject = New ComObject

Public Sub Start()
    Dim Thread1 = New Threading.Thread(Sub() DoSomething())
    Dim Thread2 = New Threading.Thread(Sub() DoSomething())
    Dim Thread3 = New Threading.Thread(Sub() DoSomething())
    Thread1.Start()
    Thread2.Start()
    Thread3.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub DoSomething()
    _App.DoSomeComLogic
End Sub
```

The logic in the COM component takes about 10 seconds to proceed. But Thread3 is finished after 30 seconds.

Is there any way to multi-thread these function calls?

Do I need to add some DoEvents in the VB6 component?

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: VB6 only supports apartment threading, your DoSomeComLogic() call is automatically marshaled to the one-and-only thread that owns the VB6 object.  Three calls therefore always take 3x as long.  You'll have to retire it to get ahead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have the source to the VB6 component, I'd recommend just rewriting it in C# - you'll get a lot more out of it (64-bit execution, threading, better primitives, etc.) VB6 is very old, unmaintained technology with numerous restrictions. What you're trying to do is possible even with VB6 but is *very*, *very* complicated and hard to get right. (Much harder than doing the same in C#.)

If the COM component is 3rd party and you cannot upgrade (meaning you have to use this old component), you can wrap your COM component (which I assume is a DLL) in an out-of-process COM server (an ActiveX EXE project in VB6).

I don't have VB6 installed at the moment but if I remember right, you can set the new server to [`SingleUse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242107%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) so a new instance starts for every request. This would give you proper parallel processing using VB6, at the cost of handling every call in a separate process. (Each process would live for about 10 seconds - probably somewhat longer because of the extra process start-up cost.) Depending on how complex the old component is, this may be a lot of work.

If you can, just convert your old VB6 component to C# - even if it's more work, at least you won't have to deal with it anymore and will be easier to maintain it going forward.

Comment: Downvoter: care to comment why you think this answer is wrong?

Comment: In the real world, sometimes you can't just upgrade or rewrite a heavily-used application. Your answer should be a comment instead. Yes, technically you answered the very last question "any better way to achieve this," but some of us would like to know how to make it work with existing structures.

Comment: @user1422348 The answer states it pretty clearly - wrap the VB6 component in an out-of-process server for stability and isolation. Also, as much as I loved VB6, it's heavily outdated technology. I'm aware of the complexity of re-writing old systems but sometimes that's the right route to take.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert on any of this, but here's how we are able to run our VB6 COM dll embedded into a .NET asmx web service concurrently. See https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/sep/18/creating-sta-com-compatible-aspnet-applications for a good writeup.

- The DLL must be set to Single-threaded apartment (STA) in the properties of the VB6 project.
- IIS pool on which the .NET project runs must be set to classic pipeline, not integrated.
- IIS pool must "enable 32-bit applications"
- You have to create a custom http handler in order to make the .NET project run in an STA environment instead of the default MTA (multi-threaded apartment). See the above link for an example (there are a few other examples out there as well). Apparently, it's very simple for aspx pages - you just set the AspCompat flag, but asmx web services can't do that, which is where the custom http handler class comes in.
- You'll need to also add your custom handler in the `<httphandlers>` section of web.config.
- If you're running .NET 4.5+, you'll also need to add `<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="false" />` to the `<appSettings>` section of web.config.

Again, I am no expert on this and I do not have a complete understanding of everything here, but this is how we were able to make it work.